# Room's AC fan on/off switching creates interference on USB cable

Tags: rf, usb, noise, mains

Turning on and off a simple AC fan (room fan) makes the communication between a device and PC via USB stop. We need to re-power the device and re-plug the USB cable to (temporary) fix the issue.

Using the fan close to the AC line of the device also makes the USB communication get stuck.

So I need to both isolate the AC line (or earth) of my device from the rest of the line, and to shield my USB cable properly.

I already have made the USB cable shorter, used a good quality shielded cable, and the GND of the circuit/USB is not connected to the earth/chassis of the device.

What I want to know is:

1. Since I do not have an RF spectrum analyzer to see the noise the AC fan creates, what kind of frequency/spectrum can I expect it to create? This information will help me determine how to design the chassis (the materials to use to suppress the noise).
2. What materials (metallic or plastic) can be used to suppress the noise an AC fan generates?
3. What kind of filtering does my device need on the AC side to suppress such noise? I think filtering like the [6EGG1C-1](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/418/5/NG_CD_6EGG1C_1_A-672733.pdf) power entry module has, would be sufficient:

[image: AC filtering]

4. Are there other communication protocols that are more noise-resistant? I guess the Ethernet protocol is one of those. (I am thinking of using a USB-to-ethernet converter on both ends.)

Comment: Why are you focusing on your USB cable when there is clearly something wrong with your AC fan? Having that much nosie coming out of an AC fan would make me very scared about using it, I'd say there is a major saftey issue there.

Comment: It might be the cheapest AC fan one can find, but it helps us re-create an issue many of out customers have with our device, which is the USB communication stucks when being used near power-hungry devices in industrial environments.

Comment: Is this happening with any combination of PCs and Fan, or just with one PC and the Fan ? The previous poster is right, you'll need to possibly consider the source of noise to your USB coms.... Otherwise a simple and quick solution that may solve your problem is a USB clip-on ferrite bead/choke that you can purchase and clip on your USB cable and retest to see if this may resolve your issue. My gut feeling though is that you have a ground problem somewhere... is your "device" battery powered or mains powered ? It may be helpful to mention that ..

Comment: Schematics and PCB needed to know if there is something wrong with the design, in order to fix it.

Comment: _”What materials (metallic or plastic) can be used to suppress the noise an AC fan generates?”_ Highly unlikely it’s radiated and you can shield yourself from it. Most probably it’s conducted and something in your system is lacking decoupling, ground plane, poor layout or lack of CM choke.

Comment: Never mind I see the device is AC powered ...